# Eigenvalues for discretization matrix in Poisson equation with finite difference

Tags: finite-differences, poissons-equation, chebyshev-polynomials

I am trying to find the eigenvalues for the discretization matrix in the Poisson equation using the Chebyshev polynomials, i.e.
$$ -u''(x) = f(x), x \in [0,1],\;\; u(0)=u(1)=0 $$
Discretize the spatial domain uniformly: $x_i = ih$ with $h=1/m, i \in \{0,1,\ldots,m\}$. Let
$$A = \begin{bmatrix} 2&-1&0&\cdots&0\\
                      -1&2&-1&\cdots&0\\
\cdots&\cdots&-1&2&-1\\
0&0&0&2&-1\\
\end{bmatrix}$$
Then the solution is approximated in finite difference by solving
$$Au = f$$

My question is how to find the eigenvealues of A using the Chebyshev polynomials. I can show the recurrence relation for $u_{k+1}$ is a special case of the Chebyshev polynomials, i.e
$$A[u^p_1,u^p_2, \cdots, u^p_{m-1}]^T \Rightarrow (A u^p)_j = -\frac{1}{h^2} \left(u_{j-1}^p -2u_j^p + u_{j+1}^p  \right) = \lambda_p u_j^p$$
$$\Rightarrow u_{j+1}^p = (2-h^2 \lambda_p)u_j - u_{j-1}$$
is a special case of
$$U_{j+1}(x) = 2xU_j(x)-U_{j-1}(z)$$
by setting $x = 1 - \frac{h^2 \lambda_p}{2}$. So with representation of the Chebyshev polynomial, I can have
$$ u_j= U_j(1 - \frac{h^2 \lambda_p}{2}) =  \frac{\sin\left[(j+1)\cos^{-1}\left(1 - \frac{h^2\lambda_p}{2}\right)\right]}{\sqrt{1 - \left(1 - \frac{h^2\lambda_p}{2}\right)^2}}$$
But how can we find the the eigenvalue from the above equation? We know that for Chebyshev polynomials $U_0(x)=1$, but I don't think $u_0 = 0 \neq U_0(1 - \frac{h^2 \lambda_p}{2})$.

Any help/hints will be greatly appreciated.
Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

I am not sure that your recurrence relation can be deal with by Chebychev polynomials. Indeed the term in front of the $u_j$ should be dependent on $j$ for that.

Rather, from the solutions of the continuous eigenvalue problem you could look for an eigenvector/value by plugging $v_p=e^{iqp}$ in the expression $-v_{p+1}+2v_p-v_{p-1}$ and get
$$-v_{p+1}+2v_p-v_{p-1}=(2-e^{iq}-e^{-iq})v_p=2(1-\cos q)v_p=4\sin^2(q/2)v_p$$
To fulfil boundary conditions, set $w_p=\sin(qp)=\frac{1}{2i}(v_p-v_{-p})$ which verifies $w_0=w_{m}=0$ if $q=\frac{k\pi}{m}$ with $k=1,\ldots,m-1$.
Then $w_p$ verifies $w_0=w_{m}=0$ and
$$-w_{p+1}+2w_p-w_{p-1}=4\sin^2(\frac{k\pi}{2m})w_p,\qquad k=1,\ldots,m-1$$
which is exactly $Aw=4\sin^2(\frac{k\pi}{2m})w$ (your matrix $A$ is of size $m-1$).
Thus you got your eigenvectors and values.